# Max upload size is limited to 10 MB on a local Wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I have a local Wordpress installation at my work place using Wamp, and I had a max upload size of 3 MB.
Following the solution I found, I edited the php.ini file from the wamp menu, increased post_max_size to 32M and upload_max_filesize to 64M and restarted the servers.

The max upload size increased in the Wordpress admin area to 10 MB, which isn't enough, and I can't tell where that number is coming from.

I searched for the phrase `10M` in the wamp's php.ini file but didn't find any.

Any idea where that number might be coming from?

Comment: Possible http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: To narrow down if its a server/php or wordpress limitation you're up against, try creating a php file containing <?php phpinfo(); ?>  to see the server upload limit :)

Comment: @flauntster, Where should that file be placed?

Comment: @ubonozur anywhere that you can bring it up in your browser, such as the root folder of the wordpress installation.

Comment: If this is WAMPServer you are using there is a link on the `localhost` homepage to a `phpinfo()` script

Comment: @flauntster, thanks but I don't quite understand.
Do you mean I should create a php file containing only the short code you wrote, place it in the root folder and then write it's path in the browser's URL?
What should I expect to see?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks. I've blocked the `localhost` homepage so that other workers in my workplace won't get there and mess things around.
Any other way to access that script?

Comment: you can try using `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );` in your wp-config.php. see the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP)

Comment: @ubonozur yes thats correct, that one php command outputs your php server's info to your browser :)

Comment: @M.Doye , why would increasing the memory limit affect upload file sizes?

Comment: @flauntster in wordpress, that directive handles both

Comment: RE: Localhost link to `phpinfo()`: No its part of the index.php script that runs the homepage. Why/How is homepage blocked? Just leave it set to `Require local` and it can only be run on the PC that is running WAMPServer. Then use a Virtual Host for each of your projects. You can then also chnage these parameters within the VHOST definition so they are specific to each project/vhost

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the PHP manual

> post_max_size integer
>
> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
> upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
> script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
> memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an integer is
> used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described
> in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater
> than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.
> This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET
> variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if
> $_GET['processed'] is set.

So your `post_max_filesize` need to be large enough to cope with the

```
(upload_max_filesize * files uploaded) + other variables
```

Also you need to check that `memory_limit` is big enough to cope as well

**The correct php.ini file**

It is also worth noting that WAMPServer, like most Apache/PHP installations has 2 different php.ini files. Maybe you are editng the wrong one?

There is one in `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` this is used by the PHP CLI ( Command Line Inteface ) and soes not affect PHP used under Apache.

The one you need to edit to affect Apache/PHP is
`\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini` but the easiest way to do that is to use the wampmanager menus.

Find the wampmanager icon in the system tray and left click then follow the menus

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will open the correct `php.ini` file, the one used by PHP when run with apache. Make the changes in this file.

Comment: These are my numbers now: memory_limit = 128M , upload_max_filesize = 32M , post_max_size = 128M. This is in wamp's php.ini. Still can upload only 10m

Comment: See my additional info in the asnwer about the editing correct `php.ini` file.

Comment: yes, I used the menus method to get to the php.ini file.
And my edits did get a result - they increased the limit from 3MB to 10MB.
So I guess it's the right file.
But something else prevents that 10MB limit from being any larger.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` file into the WordPress root and insert the following:

```
php_value post_max_size 64MB
php_value post_max_filesize 64MB
php_value upload_max_filesize 64MB
```

Then check if the values have been changed inside `wp-admin`. If they have, there is some other `php.ini` being loaded instead of the one you've been editing.

Comment: Already had a .htaccess file in the root dir and adding these lines caused the media files not to show in the media section

Comment: Did you insert the values after the base contents? Try adding them before everything else.

Comment: OK, I added them at the begining of the .htaccess file and I get the same result - the media files don't show in the media section.

Answer (score 0):

Still ran into this problem today. Fix that worked for me:

Click WAMP tray icon and select PHP/php.ini

This will open the php.ini file in the editor you chose when installing WAMP. **Note that php.ini is a shortcut to the file C:\wampDir\bin\php\php7.2.14\phpForApache.ini.** Presumably this will vary between installs.

What I found was that the upload max in WP is the lesser of these 2 settings in the php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

and

```
post_max  = 45M
```

Easy! (after over an hour of searching) ;(